# Why Does My Multidimensional Array Works Globally, but Not Scoped?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array meant to represent 1024 * 1024 2-byte values. When I declare it in global scope, my `fstream` is able to read into it. When I declare it inside the same function that calls `file.read`, I get 0xC00000FD (stack overflow exception in windows?)

The following works, returning 0 when the program is finished

[image: global md initialization]

The following does not, exiting with 0xC00000FD

[image: stack overflow exception]

Eventually, I'd like to have the `textureMap1` variable as part of a struct, but in my troubleshooting, I've found out that I can't seem to read into it, if it's not declared globally. I suspect it's something with static initialization, but I'm not familiar enough with C++ to know the nuances.

Why does the global declaration run without issue, but as soon as I move it into a scope, whether it be function scope or a struct, I get a stack overflow exception?

**Edit**

Link to Single File Header on pastebin.com

https://pastebin.com/raw/enLtebEe

To use in a project, you'll need a copy of a carnivores2 map file, as well as defining #STB_OCARN2_IMPLEMENTATION in one file, like stb headers.

Comment: Please include the code as text rather than a picture of text.

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: I believe I read that in windows there is only a 2MB (or 1MB?) stack by default, so one must be very careful with local variables (and recursion). If my memory is right, that would explain the overflow. There might be some way to prod the compiler to request a larger stack from the OS.

Comment: @chi: If I recall correctly, it is `1MB` by default, however that may have changed in recent versions of the Microsoft compiler.

Comment: The stack is a limited resource. Your textureMap is 2MB which may be larger than the default stack. On windows / msvc the default stack is 1MB

Comment: I'm using MinGW 8, if that makes any difference

Comment: `0xC00000FD` is a stack overflow.

Comment: Microsoft describes the default stack for mscv here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, programs built on Micrsoft Windows using the Microsoft compiler have a default maximum stack size of about 1 MB.

The declaration

```
unsigned short textureMap1[1024][1024];
```

allocates 2 MB on the stack, if you declare it as an automatic variable. That is why the stack overflows in your case.

If you instead declare the array as a global variable, then it won't be allocated on the stack, so it won't be a problem.

Stack space is a very limited resource, especially on Microsoft Windows (Linux has a larger default stack size of about 8 MB). Therefore, you should generally not allocate more than a few kilobytes on it, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

For allocating such large amounts of data, it is usually better to use dynamic memory allocation, such as [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) or [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), or use a container such as [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: So is the correct way to fix this `auto textureMap1 = new unsigned short[1024 * 1024];`? That would make it allocated on the heap instead of stack, right?

Comment: No. The correct way is to use `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short>> textureMap1 (1024, std::vector<unsigned short>(1024))`

Comment: @Goldentoa11: If you want to preserve the type as a multidimensional array, then you need to write `auto textureMap1 = new unsigned short[1024][1024];` instead of `auto textureMap1 = new unsigned short[1024 * 1024];`. Note however that in modern C++, it is not very common to use `new`.  It is more common to use `std::make_unique` or `std::vector`, as those make use of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) (i.e. the memory is automatically freed when the object goes out of scope, which does not happen with `new`).

Comment: The vectors are working, and I'm just going to convert it to a single dimensional array and use math. Is there a way to avoid repeating the type in the struct definition, since I can't use `auto` to define a field and initialize it with the required number of elements for reading the map?

Comment: eg `struct Map { std::vector<unsigned char> heightMap = std::vector<unsigned char>(1024 * 1024); };`

Comment: @Goldentoa11: I'm afraid I'm unaware of any way to avoid repeating the type in this situation.